# error: A value of type 'Image?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Image'. (invalid_assignment at [esp32_cam_demo_app] lib\main.dart:148)

Tags: flutter, image, android-studio, dart

I'm getting this error at flutter app.

Full code is here:

https://github.com/0015/ThatProject/blob/master/ESP32_MQTT/2_Flutter_MQTT_Client_App/mqtt_esp32cam_viewer_full_version/lib/main.dart

Can anyone have solution for error? It's important me right now.

Thanks all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see an error with `'SomeType?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SomeType'.` you are running into Dart's [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) checks.

As of Dart 2.12, variables can either receive a null value (i.e. be "nullable") or they cannot. Variables must explicitly be defined as nullable by using the `?` when defining the type, and you cannot assign nullable variables to non-nullable variables (even if they both hold the same datatype) *unless* you either:

- check that the nullable variable does currently have a non-null value (e.g. `x != null`)
- use the `!` operator to tell Dart that you are **sure** it has a non-null value.

It's a bit hard to debug your case since I can't run your code, but I would guess the error you are experiencing is due to a mismatch in nullability on this line

```
img.Image jpegImage = img.decodeJpg(recMess.payload.message!);
```

`jpegImage` is non-nullable, and even though you are saying the `message` component of the right side is non-null, I believe `recMess.payload` may be. It's a bit hard to debug this error when you are not explicitly tracking the datatypes of the variables above it in the code (i.e. `mqttMessageReceived` and `recMess`). Generally I avoid using implicit typing when nullable values are present. For your case, before assigning to the `Image` type you can check if any of these values are null. I believe in your case the issue may be that the elements of the List `mqttMessageReceived` are nullable but you did not check nullability or use the `!` operator on the individual elements.

If this is confusing I highly recommend Dart's [Null safety codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety) which has many examples and shortcuts to make working with null safety easy.